# Ruby tries to download from https://api.rubygems.org even with source key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, ssl

I downloaded Ruby installer for Windows, Installed Ruby, then tried

```
gem update --system
```

> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>
> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

```
gem update --system --source http://rubygems.org
```

> Updating installed gems
>
> ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
>
> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

How to force it to use HTTP version of the host?

- ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i386-mingw32]
- gem 2.6.7

Comment: what version of ruby are you trying to install? rubygems 2.4.4 is broken on windows. check out https://gist.github.com/luislavena/f064211759ee0f806c88

Comment: @baseballlover723: I added version information to the question.

Comment: try updating ruby gems to 2.6.8 because it has better ssl error messages and check out these github issues, they might be what your experiencing.  https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/1758. http://guides.rubygems.org/ssl-certificate-update/

Answer (score 0):

Hi sorry for the late response. Having the same problem and I've gotten to the point where it's actually api.rubygems.org sending the redirect to https!

Comment: it explains what the problem is